# Getting Special character only in the "first column of first row" while loading to a text file using informatica

Tags: file, unix, special-characters, informatica

I am trying to load a file using Informatica and getting Special character only in the "first column of first row".

I tried updating the code page to UTF-8. but still the issue exist.

The sample output:

```
Row1: ^@^@^@"12345"|abcd|Desc1~InValid
Row2:  12346|bcde|Desc2~invalid
Row3:  12146|bade|Desc3~invalid
Row4:  11346|bbde|Desc4~invalid
Row5:  12136|bcce|Desc5~invalid
Row6:  12246|bdde|Desc6~invalid
```

Can you please help?

Comment: What is your source/environment and what is the target where u see special characters?

Comment: Is this your source that your trying to load, or it's the output that get created by your mapping?

Comment: Is the sequence ^@^@^@ the actual _special character_ you see in the file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pre session command to ignore the special characters in a file. Use below unix command to avoid special characters,

```
sed -e 's/[^@]/ /g;s/  */ /g' input.sql > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses. The special characters are present in the source file itself. These are even hidden characters and are able to see only with the view of cat command output. Not with Vi editor nor with notepad view also.

Thanks again!